# passing variable to another page when it is called using curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl

I am usig curl_setopt to eval another file from a different server, the link is something like this "http://somewhere.com/index.php?vars=hello"

now in somewhere.com/index.php i need to get the value of vars that was passed using curl, but so far i cant get any values at all.

here is my sample code for your reference this is from the file calling somewhere.com:

```
$d = "http://somewhere.com/index.php?vars=hello";
$ch1 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $d);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

$data1 = curl_exec($ch1);
eval($data1);
curl_close($ch1);
```

in somewhere.com/index.php i already did print_r($_GET); to view any passed values to the file but it returned nothing.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in the index.php file with the variable "hello"? When you do a curl post to another page that other page typically will echo out a response and that response is what you evaluate. Can you post your code from index.php so we can see what you are trying to do?

Edit: Also you can use chrome inspector, fiddler or some other network monitor to see if the http request actually is being fired off and to check that you are actually getting a 200 response back.

Edit: I don't know what you are using eval either, just echo the response. If you have an output buffer issue then start buffering before you echo the response like:

```
     ob_start():
     echo $data1;
     ob_end_clean();
```

Also if you want to see if you are getting any errors just do this:

```
     if(curl_exec($ch1) === false)
     {
     echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch1);
     } 
     else
     {
     echo $data1;
     }

     // Close handle
     curl_close($ch1);
```

Comment: it states no errors also in my index.php is print_r($_GET) and print_r($_REQUEST); the request has an output but the get doesnt. also tried using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551599/php-use-curl-to-send-information-to-another-page but still not working

Comment: try using this in your index.php file instead of straight print_r:
`echo <pre> . print_r($_GET,1) . '</pre>';`

Comment: sorry it's been a while since I wrote php code the above code will error, use this:
`echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET, 1) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use `$_GET[]`?

i.e.
    `$variables = $_GET['vars'];`

Comment: edited the question, also i did but i still cant get the value